# How to change columns naming for proper sorting of Pivot table?

Tags: python, list, pandas, pivot-table

I am doing Cohort analysis for my company which consists of 2.5 year data. When constructing Pivot tables for cohort table visualizations, my order of columns get shifted (look at img).[Cohort data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUZnY.png)

I guess problem is in proper naming (I should somehow add another 0 before single digit values).

```
users['monthnum'] = users.OrderDateTime.apply(lambda x: x.month + 12*(x.year-2016))
users['running_month'] = users.monthnum - users.cohort_monthnum
users.running_month = users.running_month.astype(str) + '-month'
```

I am a newbie to data analysis in python so I am not sure how to fix this. I know if I just leave last row of code left out (so I am not making it a string #purpose is for naming for employer) cohorts work just fine (as integers are sorted correctly).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html):

```
users.running_month = users.running_month.astype(str).str.zfill(2) + '-month'
```